# sklearn | RFECV + Linear Regression gives "'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following code:

```
rfe = RFECV(estimator=LinearRegression())
model_all = LinearRegression()
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s',rfe),('m',model_all)])
# evaluate model
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
n_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_all, y_all, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
# report performance
print('RMSE: {0}'.format(np.mean(n_scores)))
```

and I'm trying to get the coefficients of the Linear Regression model to check feature importance:

```
importance = model_all.coef_
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
```

But it gives me:

> AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'

How to get the coefficients? I would also like to get the names of the columns selected using the RFECV procedure.

Comment: hey did not fit here? you need to show the model some data before it can calculate coef_.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but am I not doing this already? Otherwise how is it possible to reach a low MSE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you instantiate model:

```
model_all = LinearRegression()
```

this calculate the cv score for your pipeline:

```
n_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_all, y_all, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
```

`model_all` still vanila `LinearRegression()` object and is not fitted so it doesn't have `coef_` attribute

```
# add this
model_all.fit(X_all, y_all)
importance = model_all.coef_
```